# MOSFET representation

Tags: mosfet

In my book I often see the N-type semiconductor both drain and source being shown as n+ whereas the p-type semiconductor or the substrate is shown/represented as p only. Why is N-type semiconductors represented as n+ in a N-channel MOSFET?

Answer (score 4):

The + sign means that the layers are highly doped. So n+ would be just like an n, but would mean highly doped. Same goes with p+

Comment: And the opposite with n- and p-.

Comment: I am guessing lightly doped

Comment: No need to guess, you're exactly right.  n- is lightly doped (relative to the doping level they are calling 'n').  n-- would be almost intrinsic (and is used in sensor diodes)